# Why is my CommandArgument Empty?

Tags: asp.net, listview, commandargument

I have an ASP.Net page, which displays a list of options to the user.  When they select from the list, it does a post back and queries a sql server.  The results are displayed in a listview below the options in an update panel.  Below is a snippet of the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Save IT" OnCommand="SaveIt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server" />
```

The DataItemIndex does not appear, so my commandargument is empty.  However, the object sender is the button, which shows the item.

**Why is the index item not appearing in the CommandArgument?**

Could it be the post back? If so, why would it be the post back?  Is there a way around it?

Edit:
Sorry, from my attempts to solve it before, I posted bad code, but it still isn't appearing.

Resolution:
I found another work around in that the sender of the OnCommand is the link button, which has the CommandArgument.  I will chalk this issue up to be an issue with multiple postbacks and javascript.

Comment: almost certainly the postback...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `<%= %>` syntax inside properties on a tag with a `runat="server"` attribute. I'm surprised the code will even run. :)

**UPDATE:**

You probably want to use the ItemDataBound event on the repeater, find the linkbutton and set the CommandArgument property.

Not very elegant, but here's a VB.NET sample.

```vb
Private Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
      Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
        Dim b As LinkButton = e.Item.FindControl("btn")
        b.CommandArgument = e.Item.ItemIndex
        b.DataBind()
    End Select
  End Sub
```

Comment: I changed it to #, but it still won't display it in the CommandArgument.  It doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: I found another workaround, but your solution should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting it

You possibly want

```
<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>
```

or

```
<%= Container.DataItemIndex %>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Save IT" OnCommand="SaveIt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server" />
```

You were missing the "#" sign.

Answer (score 0):

This site really helped me with this problem: http://forums.asp.net/t/1671316.aspx

The issue I ran into was that I was being passed null arguments in the commandargument when I clicked on the button a second time. As the post above explains, this is because commandargument is only set in the databind event. So, to fix this, include a databind event in the page_load sub

Ex. (VB)

```
Private Sub BindSelectButtons()       

    'Purpose: bind the data to the select buttons for commandargument to be used
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
        gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(8).FindControl("btnID").DataBind()
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Rebind select buttons so that the commandargument refreshes
    BindSelectButtons()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure View State is enabled
e.Row.EnableViewState = true;